# 2011 Jeep Patriot broken bolt in engine cradle / cross member

Tags: jeep, frame, patriot

So, I've been noticing some sounds when the vehicle is moving, especially starting/stopping/turning, and recently had all the struts replaced, but the noise persisted. Then I noticed that there is a sheared off bolt running from the front cross member up to the frame. It appears to be broken right at the joint, so flush with where the threads start, but inside the attachment point. I'm wondering if ya'll have any advice on fixing this, but I'm also puzzled how a 13/16" hex head hardened bolt designed to hold the engine to the frame could shear off like this.

[image: front cross member with bolt location]
[image: sheared bolt]

Comment: Wow that sure is strange!

I would recommend checking other parts for signs of damage. 
Otherwise if its a stud you can probably get it out.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the original post that we bought this car off the lot in 2011, so we have seen everything that it has gone through. I first noticed the shifting sounds about a year ago, and just recently discovered the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you will be able to repair this depends on the part.

If this is a stud that is inserted into the part and has sheared, you can likely drill it out and use a Screw Extractor to remove the left in part (use lots of penetrating fluid too). This would require you to then find an appropriate stud to replace it with.

If it is not a stud, you will have to buy a whole new part, which might be advisable anyway due to safety.

It is unclear in the picture whether it is a bolt that goes through the bottom and upwards or a stud that is inside then a nut used to tighten down.

In the case that it is a bolt going through the bottom that has sheared, you can use the same screw extracting method.
A good idea is also to run through the thread with a thread tap/chaser to ensure the threads are in good shape before putting in a new stud/bolt.

Comment: It is definitely a bolt, at least if it is setup the same way as the driver side which has a 13/16 hex head bolt.

Comment: In that case, you should be fine to use a Screw extractor (large one) and remove the remains of the bolt, then replace it with an OEM or equivalent bolt.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a defective bolt or, more likely, hitting something - have you looked for any signs of damage repairs?

May just have been the wheel / hub assembly...

Comment: We've been rear ended at low speed a couple of times, and glancingly hit a deer once, but the only damage I could see at the time was a cracked turn signal. Someone mentioned going over a pothole could do this, but seems like something smaller would have broken first.